# Angular2 + SVG: Using one template for multiple components (IE fix?)

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, svg, angular2-template

I have multiple SVG icons, which use the same html template to insert a string (containing an SVG markup). It all works fine in every browser except for IE11 (I believe anything below IE11 would have the same problem).

Here is how **the template** looks:

```
<svg data-component [attr.viewBox]="vbox" preserveAspectRatio="none">
   <svg:g #svgContainer></g>
</svg>
<span *ngIf="label">{{ label | translate }}</span>
```

This is the **base icon class**, which subsequently is being extended by every other icon component:

```
import { Input, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

export class IconBase implements AfterViewInit {

  @Input('icon-label') public label: string;
  @Input('icon-vbox') public vbox: string = '0 0 30 30';

  @ViewChild('svgContainer') public svgContainer: ElementRef;

  public svgString: any = '';

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.svgContainer.nativeElement.innerHTML = this.svgString;
  }
}
```

So far so good. Now here is one **icon component**, which - as every other icon component - only sets the `svgString`. Everything else is taken care of at base icon class:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IconBase } from './icon';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'icon-view-list, [icon-view-list]',
    templateUrl: './icon.html'
})

export class IconViewListComponent extends IconBase {
    public svgString: string = `
        <path class="st0" d="M5.1,10H10V5.1H5.1V10z M12.5,5.1V10h12.4V5.1H12.5z M12.5,17.5h12.4v-4.9H12.5V17.5z M12.5,24.9h12.4V20H12.5
        V24.9z M5.1,17.5H10v-4.9H5.1V17.5z M5.1,24.9H10V20H5.1V24.9z"/>
    `;
}
```

That string can be a `path`, a `line`, a `polyline`, a `circle` - basically any SVG element.

Chrome and Firefox insert the string into the `<svg>` element, however IE does nothing - it only renders empty `<svg>`. I tried to follow an advice by namespacing the svg element where the insertion should take place, but no, that didn't help. Any suggestions? Maybe some code refactoring altogether?

Thanks.